# Upgrading Rails 3.2 to Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3.2 project that has 30 models and about 20 controllers. It's not a super huge codebase and its pretty much an idiomatic Rails site.

Is there any advantage to just doing `rails new` and controller by controller, model by model, gem by gem just copy and pasting things in and getting everything running on a fresh Rails 5 instance?

I just see some pain trying to do an upgrade version by version. Is this a viable way to upgrade a project where I have written all the code and know the project well?

Comment: I would say, its the best way to upgrade a rails app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no harm in doing that at all, it will help you move to the newer project structure and ensure all new files are in place (bin files for instance). 
You will still need to make sure you make all of the relevant code changes (`ApplicationRecord` inheritance for example) to your files.

Comment: I have this unexplainable gut feeling that this will actually be easier than trying to update the existing application. I will just put each piece in place one by one starting with things like Devise and just make sure each piece works correctly. Either way is for sure a good bit of work. My instinct is I will have better luck doing this way and it will be a nice clean Rails 5 app in the end.

Comment: I would expect the same outcome, so long as you take note of the big changes and adjust your source files appropriately after bringing them in. I would suggest building the gemfile, bundling and then running post-install steps for things like devise (to build the most modern version of the devise initializer), and THEN bringing over your code.

Comment: @slindsey3000 I'm just about to embark on the same upgrade path, also starting with a new Rails 5 template.  Any hints and tips you have in hindsight would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: @Snips I'm also in the same boat. Did you complete this migration by chance? Any major hiccups or suggestions? Thanks

Comment: @KevinZych Actually, I didn't get round to it in 2016, but have finally bitten the bullet in the past 3 months.  I chose to start from scratch with 'rails new' and migrate the code over (taking the opportunity for a code review and spring clean).  It's a lot of work (more than I remembered) but the actual rails side of the migration is more straight-forward than I expected.  Some of the ActiveRecord queries are requiring significant change though.